# In Magento Layered Navigation, how do I get all items for active filters?

Tags: magento, filter, navigation, layered

Once a filter becomes active it returns 0 items thus it won't show anymore in the "SHOPPING OPTIONS". For my custom layered nav I need to fetch and show these items. I know some extension are already doing this (and providing checkboxes next to an item) but I'd like to know how to do it myself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'll look into that. I'm just surprised that no one had done it yet (besides those ajax extensions people) and if they have, how come they're not sharing their code...

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your layered navigation filters to show up when the results are 0 for the filter then all you have to do is go to is edit the product attributes and set 
Use In Layered Navigation=Filterable (No result).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help. Let me explain better: lets say you have a "Price" filter. once you click on an item on this filter (lets say 0-$10,000) This filter won't show up anymore on the "SHOPPING OPTIONS" section. I'm using a select box in order to pick an item so I want to give the user an option to select a different item for this filter instead of clearing first and then picking the other item. Your solution still doesn't bring up that chosen filter with all it's item.  Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

In the matter of fact, its a very complex issue because you CAN'T really get the items from an active filter. This "filter" is no longer a filter, its now a state, and thus cannot give you any items (see `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\layer\state.phtml` and compare it with filter.phtml). What you CAN do is fight a little bit with `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer` models, and especially `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php`. Its a resource which does all the work with adding layers, counting products for the layers... If you're familiar with Zend Select object, and a little mysql you could quite easily achieve whatever you want with layered navigation.

As far as I know, most commercial modules use AJAX to simulate some new Layered Navigation features (they don't really mess up with it).

If you are not familiar with Magento development, layered navigation is probably the worst place to start...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'll look into that. I'm just surprised that no one had done it yet (besides those ajax extensions people) and if they have, how come they're not sharing their code...

Thanks again!